# Firefox Add-On window.addEventListener error: window not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

i'm trying to follow this tutorial for creating a firefox addon that intercept when the url in the address bar change:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners#Example:_Notification_when_the_value_in_Address_Bar_changes

I just copied the code, and just added an alert to see if it works, but i can't have it run in any way.

My code is:

```
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm", this);

var urlListener = {
    oldURL: null,

    init: function() {
        gBrowser.addProgressListener(this);
    },

    uninit: function() {
        gBrowser.removeProgressListener(this);
    },

    processNewURL: function(aURI) {
        if (aURI.spec == this.oldURL) return;

        // now we know the url is new...
        alert(aURI.spec);
        this.oldURL = aURI.spec;
    },

    // nsIWebProgressListener
    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI(["nsIWebProgressListener",
                                           "nsISupportsWeakReference"]),

    onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) {
    alert("Called");
        this.processNewURL(aURI);
    },

    onStateChange: function() {},
    onProgressChange: function() {},
    onStatusChange: function() {},
    onSecurityChange: function() {}
};

  window.addEventListener("load", function() { urlListener.init() }, false);
  window.addEventListener("unload", function() { urlListener.uninit() }, false);
```

Whenever i try to start/test this extension i receive the following error:

```
Running tests on Firefox 24.3.0/Gecko 24.3.0 ({ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}) under linux/x86-gcc3.
Error: ReferenceError: window is not defined 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid1-u33krawc1uacsa-at-jetpack/amazon_rewriter/tests/test-main.js", line 1, in 
    var main = require("./main");
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 133, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
    result = load(loader, module);
  File "resource://jid1-u33krawc1uacsa-at-jetpack/amazon_rewriter/lib/main.js", line 38, in 
    window.addEventListener("load", function() { urlListener.init() }, false);
0 of 1 tests passed.
```

Probably it's me that i don't understand something from the tutorial/extension creation process.

Can you help me to understand what is missing?

**EDIT**
After kapep answer, i resolved the window not defined error. But it seems that nothing happen when i change the url in the address bar. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no global `window` or `gBrowser` objects, you need to get the browser and choose which window (`nsIDOMWindow`) you want to add the listener. This part seems to be missing or out of scope in the tutorial.

```
var gBrowser = windowUtils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().getBrowser();
```

There are probably multiple ways to get a window. I would do this is using the low-level [windowUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils) API. You could get the most recent one like above with `getMostRecentBrowserWindow` or more reliable get all currently opened windows with `windowUtils.windows()` like this:

```
const windowUtils = require("sdk/window/utils");

for each (let window in windowUtils.windows()) {
    urlListener.init();
    window.addEventListener("unload", function() { urlListener.uninit(); }, false);
}
```

Just in case you also want to add the listener to all windows opened in the future, you can add them when a new window opens:

```
const windows = require("sdk/windows");
windows.browserWindows.on("open", domWindow => {
    urlListener.init();
    windowUtils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().addEventListener("unload", function() { urlListener.uninit(); }, false);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that removes the window not defined problem, but now it seems that whenevere i insert anything in any tab nothing happens. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Ivan There should be an 'alert' popup but I'm not sure if alerts can even work in this context. You could try to add some `console.log` messages instead and see if they show up in the console.

Comment: Oh and also I don't know how you get the `gBrowser`, but I did it using `windowUtils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().getBrowser()`. Not sure if this is a good way though but it seems to work for me.

Comment: This was in the example!! :(

Comment: Ok things start workgin with your informations. just one thing is still not working well, the listener seems to be fully loaded only when i open a new window, on the first window the init method is not called. Maybe i need to call it manually? (Thanks a lot for you help)

Comment: Yeah, my bad. The current window probably is already loaded so the event doesn't fire. I updated the answer.

Comment: Many thanks!! Now everithing works! :) (hey there are two typos in the  code, just missing parenthesis.  And i think it could be useful to add the answer, also a reference to the gBrowser problem!)