# Firefox addon: new tab extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, dom-events

I need to do some actions when new tab in Firefox is opened. I'm using addon-sdk and I'm totally new to firefox extensions development.

I downloaded some new tab extensions in store, unpack them and mostly of them use such code:

```
var newtab = {
    init: function ()
    {
        gBrowser.addEventListener("NewTab", newtab.opentab, false);
    },

    opentab: function (aEvent)
    {
        // action here
    }
}

window.addEventListener( "load", newtab.init, false);
```

They are subscribing on load event of window, then they guaranteed have gBrowser to subscribe on new tab opened event.

When I'm trying to do this, I'm getting:

> Message: ReferenceError: window is not defined

As far as I understood, there is no window object in that context.

[Firefox Addon-sdk. On page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load)

[StackOverflow – Firefos Addon: eventlistener: windows is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19234254/1541660)

According to sdk and SO answer, It's possible to do it described way, the only difference between my extension and downloaded extensions from the store (and above topics), that *I haven't any xul files, because I haven't any UI*.

I also tried to use code from SO answer [Firefox Add-On window.addEventListener error: window not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22425232/1541660), but the Firefox is crashing.

How to do it right way? Should I have any xul files if I have no UI?

Comment: Did you come to a working solution ? Can you share it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thar code you're quoting is regular XUL overlay code, and does not apply to the SDK (well, it could be made to work in the SDK by jumping through a lot of hoops, but that's beside the point).

The SDK provides APIs for dealing with tabs in the [`sdk/tabs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) module. You should use that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var data = require('sdk/self').data;

require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
  include: ["about:newtab"],
  //contentScriptFile: [data.url('cs.js')], // <<< you dont need this unless you want to run stuff inside the about:newtab page
  attachTo: ["existing", "top"], // <<<< im not sure what this does
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit('attached', true);
  }
});

self.port.on('attached', function() {
  console.log('new tab page loaded!!!');
});
```

disclaimer: im not an sdk guy, this might fail, so you might have to tweak it after implementing, but im pretty sure its in the right direction